# SFMC RetrieveRequest and Subscriber object - pull back Date-type attributes in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Within the Saleforce Marketing Cloud, looking to perform a Retrieve with SOAP API  that returns the date-type attributes in YYYY-MM-DD format, rather than D/MM/YYYY. The Retrieve requests currently return dates back in  D/MM/YYYY format, which does not work so well for non-US clients.

The account's default setting as UK date format as well as their API user's setting, but we keep getting back D/MM/YYYY.

Comment: Are you looking at the raw SOAP XML response message? Typically xsd:dateTime values are transferred in ISO 8601. That might not be the case here, but it's worth ruling out a conversion being done by the client app.